# How to convert time for x-axis to create a plot?

Tags: string, matlab, plot

Currently I have a code that imports two sets of data which I would like to make a plot of however, one of the data is a raw data which needs to converted to `dd/mmm/yyy HH:MM:SS` format.

This is the code I am working with:

```
time = [1435763099;1435763109;1435763119;1435763129]; 
value = [0;0;0;0]
```

And I am planning to create a plot with this.

However, I would like to convert the time data into `dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS` format

I have tried a method of conversion using this

```
time = datestr(719529+time/86400,'dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

But still unsure how to implement this into the x-axis

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot in order the values for `x = 1:length(value)`, then using the following to change the name of the x ticks:

```
 value = [10; 20; 5; 30];
 x = 1:length(value);
 time = datestr(719529+time/86400,'dd/mmm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
 plot(x,value);
 set(gca,'xtick',x,'xticklabel',time);
 xtickangle(45)
```

Comment: It works when I try this code however my code is a little different,
where

I need the 
    plot(x,value)

to be 
    plot(time,value)